# Report Studio: Schedulling query with variable date

Tags: db2, report, cognos

I am trying to filter a query by today's month and the 6 month before that one. I would like to have that query in a schedule so that it runs once a month. This should make the actual and the 6 before change with each month. I'm using db2.

Now I have something like this in my where clause (for the 6 months earlier):
 (date>= TIMESTAMP ('2012-07-01-00.00.00.00') and date<= TIMESTAMP ('2013-1-1-00.00.00.00'))

Is there a way to get the timestamp of today's month first day and of the 6 months before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unwieldy, but you could do something like this. DB2 doesn't really have a good mechanism for declaring variables outside of stored procs. I added the `LAST_DAY` bit, too, just for convenience/reference.

```sql
WITH 

THIS_MONTH(FIRST_DAY, LAST_DAY) AS (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP_ISO(
        CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAYS
    ),
    TIMESTAMP_ISO(
        CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAYS 
    ) + 1 MONTH - 1 MICROSECOND
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
),

SIX_MONTHS_AGO(FIRST_DAY, LAST_DAY) AS (
    SELECT FIRST_DAY - 6 MONTHS,
           (FIRST_DAY - 6 MONTHS) + 1 MONTH - 1 MICROSECOND
    FROM THIS_MONTH
)

SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE UPDATE_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
    (SELECT FIRST_DAY FROM SIX_MONTHS_AGO)
    AND
    (SELECT FIRST_DAY FROM THIS_MONTH)
```